# How to select in a numpy array all paris with a defined index difference?

Tags: python, numpy, select, indexing

Let's say that I have this numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.normal(size=(5,5))
```

which result in:

[image]

I would like to select all pairs with a specific indexes distance along each row.
For example if I choose a index distance 4 along each row I expect to have:

```
res[0,0]=1.76,res[0,1]=2.24
res[1,0]=0.40,res[1,1]=1.86 

res[2,0]=-0.97,res[2,1]=-0.10
res[3,0]=0.95,res[3,1]=0.41

...
....
```

I now that I could that with a for cycle but I would like to have something smarter. I was thing to create two list of indexes and then to fill res but also in this I need a cycle.

Best

Comment: why `res[1,0]=0.40`? how do you calculate it?

Comment: res[1,0]=data[0,1]. I am probably not clear. Basically, they are all the pairs with a difference in the i index of 4 where data[i,j]. res[0,:] are the first members of the pairs and red[1,0] the second members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### hstack

I guess that something in the line of

```py
win=3 # Size of window. You say 4, but what you describe is 3 in my view. But you know how to add 1 if needed :D

np.hstack((data[:, :data.shape[1]-win].reshape(-1,1), data[:, win:].reshape(-1,1)))
```

should do

Result is

```
array([[ 1.76405235,  2.2408932 ],
       [ 0.40015721,  1.86755799],
       [-0.97727788, -0.10321885],
       [ 0.95008842,  0.4105985 ],
       [ 0.14404357,  0.12167502],
       [ 1.45427351,  0.44386323],
       [ 0.33367433,  0.3130677 ],
       [ 1.49407907, -0.85409574],
       [-2.55298982, -0.74216502],
       [ 0.6536186 ,  2.26975462]])
```

Explanation:
`data[:,:data.shape[1]-win]` is

```
array([[ 1.76405235,  0.40015721],
       [-0.97727788,  0.95008842],
       [ 0.14404357,  1.45427351],
       [ 0.33367433,  1.49407907],
       [-2.55298982,  0.6536186 ]])
```

So, just the first columns of `data`. Number of column, `data.shape[1]-win`, being the number of possible columns for data's width and win size.

Likewise, `data[:, win:]` is

```
array([[ 2.2408932 ,  1.86755799],
       [-0.10321885,  0.4105985 ],
       [ 0.12167502,  0.44386323],
       [ 0.3130677 , -0.85409574],
       [-0.74216502,  2.26975462]])
```

Which are this time the last columns (same number of columns), but separated by `win` indexes.

`.reshape(-1,1)` flatten vertically those data, if I may use this "flatten vertically" description. For example `data[:,:data.shape[1]-win].reshape(-1,1)` is the same but with 10 rows of 1 column instead of 5 rows of 2 columns.

```
array([[ 1.76405235],
       [ 0.40015721],
       [-0.97727788],
       [ 0.95008842],
       [ 0.14404357],
       [ 1.45427351],
       [ 0.33367433],
       [ 1.49407907],
       [-2.55298982],
       [ 0.6536186 ]])
```

`hstack` put those two together.

### Indexation

Another method, maybe closer to the one you're apparently about to create indexes list, would be

```py
W=data.shape[1]-win # number of pair per row
iy=np.arange(len(data)*2*W)//W//2
ix=np.array([[i,i+win] for i in range(W)]*len(data)).flatten()
data[iy,ix].reshape(-1,2)
```

That is about 2 times longer in term of cpu time. But it is worth noting that most of cpu time is spend in the creation of indexes `ix` and `iy`. So if you have many data sets of the same shape, this option could be faster, since you compute `ix` and `iy` once for all

Answer (score 1):

You can take elements by pairs of indices with [`numpy.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
np.take(data, [[0, 3], [1, 4]], axis=1).reshape(data.shape[0] * 2, 2)
```

---

```
array([[ 1.76405235,  2.2408932 ],
       [ 0.40015721,  1.86755799],
       [-0.97727788, -0.10321885],
       [ 0.95008842,  0.4105985 ],
       [ 0.14404357,  0.12167502],
       [ 1.45427351,  0.44386323],
       [ 0.33367433,  0.3130677 ],
       [ 1.49407907, -0.85409574],
       [-2.55298982, -0.74216502],
       [ 0.6536186 ,  2.26975462]])
```